# Customização do Autocomplete UI JQuery

Tags: jquery, autocompletar

Olá! Coloquei o autocomplete ui jquery no meu sistema, está funcionando como deveria, mas queria editar o visual dele.

Por exemplo, colocar uma cor de fundo nas sugestões que aparecem e não permitir a criação de uma `<div>` ao selecionar um valor.

Essa é a imagem do autocomplete como está:
  [image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPsc7.jpg]

O modelo do autocomplete que estou usando é esse https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: Você não que que apareça a div com os resultados da busca?

Comment: Coloquei uma outra imagem, repare que quando seleciono um valor ele acrescenta uma div abaixo do formulário. Essa div que eu não quero que apareça

Comment: Não entedi. Qual div?

Comment: Seria bom vc colocar o código de como está fazendo isso, porque o plugin não tem esses botões que vc colocou na imagem.

Comment: os botões são da aplicação, estou usando o ui apenas para o autocomplete. Toda a customização do site é feita com bootstrap

Comment: Sim, mas qual a div que vc se refere? Vc diz esse espaço vazio abaixo do input?

Comment: O texto com o nome da cidade que está aparecendo abaixo do for. Repara, selecionei "Rio de contas" e ele copiou o que está no input e criou uma div abaixo do form com esse valor. Mas isso é o de menos, eu quero mesmo é conseguir colocar uma cor de fundo na caixa que aparece as sugestões do autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue alterar a cor da caixa dos resultados da busca alterando via CSS o estilo da `div #ui-id-1`, que é a `div` padrão dos resultados do plugin:

```
<style>
#ui-id-1{
   background: red; /*fundo vermelho*/
}
</style>
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```css
#ui-id-1{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Quando à `div` *indesejada*, você pode inspecionar no navegador e pegar a classe ou `id` dela e esconder no CSS via `display: none`.

Comment: Tentei customizar o id que vc me passou, mas não funcionou. Estou usando um modelo diferente de autocomplete que vc usou no exemplo. Editei minha pergunta e coloquei o modelo que estou usando.

Comment: É esse mesmo que usei.

Comment: Consegui pegar pela classe "ui-menu-item". Agora, a div que ele cria no final do formulário não tem id, nem classe. Não consigo ocultar, ou nem permitir que ele crie essa div. Fui tentar ler o arquivo JS, mas está sem indentação, impossível de ler.

Comment: Consegui tirar a div também dvd. Tinha uma classe nela, eu não tinha visto. Muito obrigado!